# How can I make `python3 -m venv` install the new version of pip in the environment?

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, python-venv

I am trying to understand why these two commands produce different results in my MacOS:

```
leme:Temp ar$ virtualenv env1
Using base prefix '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7'
New python executable in /Users/ar/Temp/env1/bin/python3.7
Also creating executable in /Users/ar/Temp/env1/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
done.
leme:Temp ar$ source env1/bin/activate
(env1) leme:Temp ar$ pip install pygments
Collecting pygments
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5c/73/1dfa428150e3ccb0fa3e68db406e5be48698f2a979ccbcec795f28f44048/Pygments-2.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pygments
Successfully installed pygments-2.4.2
(env1) leme:Temp ar$ deactivate
```

In the second case, if I use it as a module, it emits a warning about the use of version 19.0.3 of pip! I don't have this old version installed in my system:

```
leme:Temp ar$ python3 -m venv env2
leme:Temp ar$ source env2/bin/activate
(env2) leme:Temp ar$ pip install pygments
Collecting pygments
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5c/73/1dfa428150e3ccb0fa3e68db406e5be48698f2a979ccbcec795f28f44048/Pygments-2.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pygments
Successfully installed pygments-2.4.2
You are using pip version 19.0.3, however version 19.2.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
(env2) leme:Temp ar$ deactivate
```

Any idea? Very strange!

Comment: What different results are you talking about? The warning from pip?

Comment: When you run the activate, then it has it's own pip installed on the PATH. If it works, does it matter which version it is?

Comment: Yes the difference in the pip

Comment: It matters for understanding what is going on

Comment: OK, now that I know that virtualenv and venv are two different tools. I rephrased the question.